# Python unable to install sklearn and datasets

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn, install.packages

From this particular website
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html
 I was trying to install a PIP called sklearn and datasets, by using 
`

```
pip install sklearn`
 pip install datasets
    .
```

They have been succesfuuly downloaded 
but when I try to import that particular packages, I couldn't import that package. 
I am newbie to this packages and dependencies in python. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to install the dataset separately. Scikit-learn has infrastructure to download them on the fly. Also, the pip package name is `scikit-learn`, not `sklearn`.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it was installed as you have to type the following:

pip install -U scikit-learn

Also, Im not sure if datasets can be downloaded via pip.

I think youre confusing installing a package and importing a package into code.

I think you may need a brief intro to python programming.  'Automate the boring stuff' and 'learn python the hard way' are great and succinct intros that will get you up to speed on why your question is confusing at best and misguided at worst:)

installation guide for scikitlearn
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html